# Send data into mysql from php using ajax without reresh or reload

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forms

I have not found anything to
All I found was forms with text fields.

My problem is:
I have 2 buttons that call a backend PHP code (Setvote.php).

```
$ipid = $row['ipid'];
$confirmed = 0;
$fake = 0;
if (isset($_POST['confirmedVote'])) {
    $confirmed = 1;
} else if (isset($_POST['fakeVote'])) {
    $fake = 1;
} else {

}

if ($confirmed + $fake == 1){
 $sqlInsert = 'INSERT INTO database (postid, ipid, confirmed, fake) values 
   ('.$id.', '.$ipid.', '.$confirmed.', '.$fake.')';
   $dbInsert = mysqli_Query($connection, $sqlInsert);
}
```

And that's the form from index.php

```
       //FORM
    if ($countIpVoted == 0) {
        echo '<br>'.'<form name="myform" action="setvote.php" method="POST" >';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="postId" value="'.$postid.'" />';
        echo '<button class="votetrue" type="submit" name="confirmedVote" id="trues"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> True</button>';
        echo '<button class="votefalse" type="submit" name="fakeVote" id="falses"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> False</button>';
        echo'</form>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<p style="padding-top:6px; padding-bottom:6px;">You have already voted this post.</p>';
        $rowIpVoted = $resultIpVoted->fetch_assoc();
```

How do i send the data to mysql without refresh the page?
I tried something like this:

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'setvote.php',
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                success: function () {

                }
            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: `I tried something like this` Looks good to me. Why do you think that this doesn't work?

Comment: When i press the true or false button, they're not dissapearing after the action, and the vote is not stored into db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```
$.ajax({
                url: "setvote.php ",
                type: "POST",
                data:  new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                processData:false,
                success: function(data)
                { }
});
```

And also make,
`action=""` in form tag

Comment: i made action =" ", put the ajax, code. Buttons do nothing.

Comment: The page does nothing, but if i put an alert into succes function of ajax, it prompts me the alert, without refreshing :)

Comment: Kindly do check Network tab in Inspect element section, if this posting was happening or not? and also check console tab, if there is any error was found??

Comment: Console doesnt found any error, and for the newtork, the setvote.php was called with status 200. But nothing into db.

Answer (score 0):

Try it. May be it will work with your code.
$(function () {

```
    $('.votetrue,.votefalse').on('click', function (e) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('postId',$('input[name="postId"]').val());
        fd.append($(this).attr('name'),$(this).attr('id'));
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'setvote.php',
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function () {

            }
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: This doesnt work, but if i press one of the buttons, the page refresh but nothing with mysql or vote.

Comment: You can check the post data by var_dump at setvote.php and can check at the network tab of the chrome browset after inspect.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the `data` of the code it should be a pair of `key:value` if you want to use the data in the php cose  so change the data to 
`data :{serial : $('form').serialize()}`
Also mention `datatype`

Comment: i dont understand properly :( could you write the code if you want?